# Existing website that requires multiple users to access the same data

Tags: php, mysql, permissions, user-permissions

I have an existing website, that doesn't use any specific framework. This project is much older and is slowly being evolved, which is somewhat of a nightmare really.

Currently, I am trying to implement a better solution to current users to have 'assistants' to their accounts.

The current data resides like this (users & contacts tables):

```
**users table**
userId, email,         password...
1       test@test.com, pa$$word
2       ass@test.com,  pa$$word

**contacts table**
contactId, userId, fName, lName...
1,         1,      john,  doe
```

I am trying to figure out how to modify my site to enable userId's (1&2), to be able to access this contact.

Instead of starting over, any direction or samples that I could glean from on how to solve this issue of mine? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the userId column from the contacts table and create a new table contacts_users with two columns, contactId and userId.This is called a PIVOT TABLE and allows many-to-many relationships like what you are describing.

Comment: How would you go about migrating an existing platform to this? Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Basically you need to create a new pivot table for every type of data as well? If I want to share data for Calendar events, create a new table with the same calendar_users?